# How to change Pycharm 'copy' and 'paste' function to ctrl+c and ctrl+v?

Tags: pycharm

I am running Pycharm 5.0.4.
shortcut to copy is :<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
shortcut to paste is: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd>

How can I change all the basic editing functionalities in pycharm?
for example I like to have <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as shortcut for Copy.

Answer (score 16):

Go to `File -> Settings -> vim emulations`, click on the `Handler` column of the `copy row` and set it to `IDE`. Do the same for paste also.

Comment: I changed to ```Ctrl+C | Copy | IDE``` and ```Ctrl+V | Paste | IDE``` then it works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you have been install VIM Emulator into Pycharm. Try to click on Tools > Vim Emulator to disable then. For me, these was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Go to File > Settings > Keymaps an make sure the keymap is "Default". 
Other keymaps (e.g. Emacs) can use different shortcuts for the most common actions, hence <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> won't work as desired

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Configuring Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html?origin=old_help). Settings -> Keymap is where actions such as copy are mapped to keyboard shortcuts. You can add a new mapping, remove the old mapping, etc.

Additionally, you can choose an entire keymap scheme. That might be your issues. You might, for example, want the Visual Studio scheme.

Answer (score 0):

for Mac users :
Preferences -> Keymap -> change to Mac OS